# Android - How to change canvas to relative layout

Tags: android, canvas

I want to add canvas to relative layout. How, I do this ?

```
   public class Board extends View{
    Canvas c;
    public Board(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        character = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.female_char_2);
        bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ice_texture);
        //ARENA LAYOUT is Relative Layout
         arenaLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.arena_layout);                  
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.setBitmap(bg.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true));
        //set Background
        Rect area = new Rect();
        area.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());


        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(area, paint);

        //menggambar
        menggambar(x,y,canvas);

        if(x < canvas.getWidth()) {
            x = x + 10;
        } else {
            y = y + 10;
            x = 0;
        }


    }

    private void menggambar(int x2, int y2, Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        canvas.drawBitmap(character, x2, y2, paint);
        arenaLayout.addView(getApplicationContext());
    }

}
```

I want to add canvas to relative layout which possess name arenaLayout. How to add canvas to 'arenaLayout' relative layout.

**If you confuse read my source code. You can give simple code to add canvas to relative layout**

Answer (score 0):

may be you want something in this way...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
   ...........
   ..........
   onCreate(Bundle savedInstances)
{
    ........
        super.oncreate(savedInstances);
      arenaLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.arena_layout); 
     Board board = new Board(this);
      setContentView(board) ;
    ..........
    }
}
```

or you can add the view to relativeLayout here.

Comment: Is those code make canvas inside relative layout? I just want to know simple code to add canvas inside relative layout